# 501 Unsupported method ('POST')

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

Good day

May you please assist I'm trying to create a simple login page but I keep on getting an error: "Message: Unsupported method ('POST'). Error code explanation: 501 - Server does not support this operation." I have attached the pictures of my code please assist

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL, pymysql
import hashlib

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Core123"

# Enter your database connection details below
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "Core@123!"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "pythonlogin"

# Initialize MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app)


@app.route("/http://localhost:5000//", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]

        # Retrieve the hashed password
        hash = hashlib.sha1((password + app.secret_key).encode()).hexdigest()

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s",
            (username, hash),
        )
        account = cursor.fetchone()

        if account:
            session["loggedin"] = True
            session["id"] = account[0]
            session["username"] = account[1]
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        else:
            msg = "Incorrect username/password!"
            return render_template("index.html", msg=msg)

    return render_template("index.html", msg="")


@app.route("/home")
def home():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        return "Logged in successfully!"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I tried testing MYSQL workbench for connectivity moved all return statements after the "POST". updated all library such as FLASK and Flask MySQL dB

Comment: Which URL are you calling? You probably don't want `http://...` inside your route path: `@app.route("/http://localhost:5000//"` - This should probably be `/login` or something similar? (as you've done for `home`)

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the hostname and method off the [route](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#routing).

```py
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

instead of

```py
@app.route("/http://localhost:5000//", methods=["GET", "POST"]) # wrong
```

Comment: Just did I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Thank you for your respond O. Jones but I still get the same error when I change the code to what you asked me to do. <code>@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST", "DELETE"])
def login():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        return "You are already logged in!"

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]</code>